# What is the quickest / easiest way to create a new file in the command line?

Tags: bash, command-line-interface

I'm sure that there are many ways to do this (`cat > foo.txt`, vim, etc) a la https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/create-files-in-linux-unix-from-bash/ but I'm not advanced enough to understand if there's anything else that's being done by using these different commands to create my file (e.g., perhaps a file created in vim has different properties than one created with the `cat` command above).

Looking to maximize ease, speed and purity (no additional properties) of the file created. Thanks!

Comment: `man touch`  (I always wanted to say that)

Comment: just use: `> your-file`

Comment: Thanks! Any reason for the `>` vs `touch`? I understand creating a file with the latter is simply a side effect of that command. Is the former the "official" create file command then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very easy is to use `touch` :

```
touch myfile
```